# Render a button (when hovered) for only one element of an array, when mapping an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
const Chat = () => {
const bodyRef = useRef(null)
const [{messages,roomMessages,roomID,socket,user}, dispatch] = useStateValue()
const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false)
useEffect(()=>{
    const setScreen = () =>{
        bodyRef.current.scrollTop = bodyRef.current.scrollHeight
    }

    setScreen()
},[])
const updateMessages = (message) =>{
    const allMessages = messages
    allMessages.push(message)
    dispatch({
        type: "SET_MESSAGES",
        item: allMessages
    })
    bodyRef.current.scrollTop = bodyRef.current.scrollHeight
}
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('new-message', (message) =>{
        if(messages === null){
            console.log('here it was null')
        } else {
            updateMessages(message)
        }
    })
    // clean up socket on unmount

}, [])
const handleDropdown = (index) =>{
    setDropdown(true)
    console.log(index)
    if(dropdown === true){
        setDropdown(false)
    }
}
return (
        <div className={'chat'}>
            <ChatHeader/>
            <div ref={bodyRef}  className={'chat__body'}>
                {messages?.map((item,index)=>(
                    <Emojify  key={item._id}>
                        <div
                            onMouseEnter={() => handleDropdown(index)}                                 
                            onMouseLeave={handleDropdown}
                            className={`chat__message ${item.name === user.displayName && "chat__reciever"}`}>
                            <h5  className={'chat__messageUser'}>
                                {item.name}
                            </h5>
                            <p className={'chat__messagetext'}>
                                {item.message}
                            </p>
                            {dropdown && <Button><ArrowDropDownIcon/></Button>}
                            {item.img && <img alt={''} className={'chat__img'} src={item.imgURL}/>}
                        </div>
                    </Emojify>
                    ))}
            </div>
            <div className={'chat__footer'}>
                <ChatFooter/>
            </div>
        </div>

);
```

I want to render the Button `{dropdown && <Button><ArrowDropDownIcon/></Button>}` when it is hovered over.

Right now if I hover over one div it gets rendered for all other mapped divs but I don't want this; it shoul be for a specific div only.

How would I do this? Does someone have an idea? I passed index but can't seem to use it as I desire.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing a single "global" boolean for dropdown open or not (*which all mapped elements are reading*), you could correlate a specific dropdown you want to be open. It's good you are already passed an index to the handler.

Change state to store null (no dropdown) or an index (show dropdown).

```
const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(null);
```

Update the handler to store/toggle an index.

```
const handleDropdown = (index) =>{
  setDropDown(value => value === index ? null : index);
}
```

In the render simply check if the current index matches the `dropdown` state.

```
<div
  onMouseEnter={() => handleDropdown(index)}
  onMouseLeave={() => handleDropdown(index)} // <-- handle index in mouse leave
  className={`chat__message ${
    item.name === user.displayName && "chat__reciever"
  }`}
>
  <h5 className={"chat__messageUser"}>{item.name}</h5>
  <p className={"chat__messagetext"}>{item.message}</p>
  {dropdown === index && ( // <-- check index match with dropdown value
    <Button>
      <ArrowDropDownIcon />
    </Button>
  )}
  {item.img && (
    <img alt={""} className={"chat__img"} src={item.imgURL} />
  )}
</div>
```